# Spring Boot Example Understanding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Boot for reading and writing into CSV file but I uanble to understand @Bean tag. Why we are using this tag for processing or writing.

For example :

```
@Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }
```

I also have another question why we are passing `step1` within get method?

Answer (score 0):

`Bean` annotation is to create a bean of type `Step`, you can inject this bean to the `job`.

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public Job importUserJob(Step step) { // auto-wired the bean
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener())
            .flow(step) // note this
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

The Bean annotation is not required if you are directly calling the step1 method to job

```
@Bean
public Job importUserJob() { // no args
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener())
            .flow(step1()) // directly calling the method
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

In the example the step and job on the same class, so they have directly called the method, but if they both on different class then you have to make them as bean and inject in the class you need.

`step1` is the step name created from the factory `stepBuilderFactory`

**UPDATE**

Execute your application with and without Bean annotation, get the list of bean definitions, if your method is annotated with Bean you'll get a bean from context

```
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringBoot.class, args);
    String[] beans = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    for (String bean : beans) {
        System.out.println(bean);
    }
```

Comment: Still @Bean is not clear. Can you please elaborate it more with some example?

Comment: it is similar to defining a bean in XML `<bean id="{bean-name}" class="{class-name}">`, if you annotate a method with bean tag,  a bean will be created and that bean can be injected anywhere, please see the code I have posted, I annotated the job method with `@Autowired` and passing the `Step step` as argument, step bean will get auto-wired